# Spark: Calculate event end time on 30-minute intervals based on start time and duration values in previous rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with event_time field, each record is generated every 30 minutes and indicates how many seconds the event lasted.
Example:

```
Event_time | event_duration_seconds
09:00      | 800
09:30      | 1800
10:00      | 2700
12:00      | 1000
13:00      | 1000
```

I need to transform consecutive  events into only one with its duration time. Output file should  look like this:

```
Event_time_start | event_time_end | event_duration_seconds
09:00            | 11:00          | 5300
12:00            | 12:30          | 1000
13:00            | 13:30          | 1000
```

Is there a method in **Scala Spark** to compare a dataframe record with the next One?

I tried with a `foreach` loop but is not a good option since it is a huge volume of data to process

Comment: I think you are looking for window functions in scala: https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: How is `event_time_end` calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a trivial problem, but here's a solution with steps as follows:

1. Create a UDF to compute the next closest 30-minute event end-time `event_ts_end` using the `java.time` API
2. Use  Window function `lag` for event time from previous row
3. Use `when/otherwise` to generate column `event_ts_start` with a `null` value if the event time difference from the previous row is 30 minutes
4. Use Window function `last(event_ts_start, ignoreNulls=true)` to backfill `null`s with the last `event_ts_start` value
5. Group data by `event_ts_start` to aggregate `event_duration` and `event_ts_end`

First, let's assemble a sample dataset:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import spark.implicits._

val df = Seq(
  (101, "2019-04-01 09:00", 800),
  (101, "2019-04-01 09:30", 1800),
  (101, "2019-04-01 10:00", 2700),
  (101, "2019-04-01 12:00", 1000),
  (101, "2019-04-01 13:00", 1000),
  (220, "2019-04-02 10:00", 1500),
  (220, "2019-04-02 10:30", 2400)
).toDF("event_id", "event_time", "event_duration")
```

Note that the sample dataset has been slightly generalized to include more than a single event and make event time include `date` info to cover cases of an event crossing a given date.

**Step `1`**:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp

def get_next_closest(seconds: Int) = udf{ (ts: Timestamp, duration: Int) =>
  import java.time.LocalDateTime
  import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

  val iter = Iterator.iterate(ts.toLocalDateTime)(_.plusSeconds(seconds)).
    dropWhile(_.isBefore(ts.toLocalDateTime.plusSeconds(duration)))

  iter.next.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))
}
```

**Steps `2 - 5`**:

```
val winSpec = Window.partitionBy("event_id").orderBy("event_time")

val seconds = 30 * 60

df.
  withColumn("event_ts", to_timestamp($"event_time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")).
  withColumn("event_ts_end", get_next_closest(seconds)($"event_ts", $"event_duration")).
  withColumn("prev_event_ts", lag($"event_ts", 1).over(winSpec)).
  withColumn("event_ts_start",  when($"prev_event_ts".isNull ||
    unix_timestamp($"event_ts") - unix_timestamp($"prev_event_ts") =!= seconds, $"event_ts"
  )).
  withColumn("event_ts_start", last($"event_ts_start", ignoreNulls=true).over(winSpec)).
  groupBy($"event_id", $"event_ts_start").agg(
    sum($"event_duration").as("event_duration"), max($"event_ts_end").as("event_ts_end")
  ).show
// +--------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
// |event_id|     event_ts_start|event_duration|       event_ts_end|
// +--------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
// |     101|2019-04-01 09:00:00|          5300|2019-04-01 11:00:00|
// |     101|2019-04-01 12:00:00|          1000|2019-04-01 12:30:00|
// |     101|2019-04-01 13:00:00|          1000|2019-04-01 13:30:00|
// |     220|2019-04-02 10:00:00|          3900|2019-04-02 11:30:00|
// +--------+-------------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm trying this silution but  having some issues ,I guess  it is because our  scala version is 1.6

Comment: @mabe, `to_timestamp` is not available prior to Spark 2.2.  You can replace `to_timestamp($"event_time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")` with `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"event_time", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))`.

Comment: Hey @Leo , I tried  your solution, adapting it to spark 1.6.0

I'm almost there!!  but  having a last problem  with function *last*  . The  sql library that I'm  working with doesn't support  *ignoreNulls* parameter so I cannot filter null values when  trying  to set event_ts_start value.

Could you please help me with an option for this step. I think is the only thing that i'm missing so far.  

Thank you!

Comment: Hi! finally I could fix the  issue .
I didn't have to write the UDF to calculate end-time, I could run date calculations in SQLText in a Hive Context.

the most dificult part was to  aggregate  records but identifing the contiguos blocks. Thanks for yout help.

Comment: here is the code 


` val newDF: DataFrame = records.withColumn( "dt_event_start",  when((lag(records("dt_real"), 1).over(winSpec).isNull ) or (lag(records("dt_real"), 1).over(winSpec)!== records("dt_prv_calc") ),records("dt_real"))).
      withColumn("dt_event_start", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max("dt_event_start" ).over(winSpec)).
      groupBy("dia","eutrancellfdd","dt_event_start").agg("dt_nxt_calc"->"max","reg" ->"sum") `